# npm package installed via github - package can't be resolved, angular 4 / webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, github, npm

I've had to fork a package to fix a couple of issues it had and while npm install seems to complete and the package ends up in node_modules

[image]

I get build errors (could not resolve package) and red sqigglies in my typescript files:

[image]

I installed it like this:

```
npm install mjharper84/adal-angular4 --save
```

from

```
https://github.com/mjharper84/adal-angular4
```

My package json looks like:

```
  "adal-angular4": "github:mjharper84/adal-angular4"
```

I have heard some prepublish script may need to run to build the package properly but I'm not sure how to implement it and can't find any examples. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mjharper84/adal-angular4` `package.json` main script is wrong, change it to: `"main": "dist/index.js"`